# Desktop and Documents in Finder

Tags: icloud, finder

In the Finder of my new Mac, there are two things I don't understand:

1) in the sidebar `Desktop` and `Documents` are placed under `iCloud`.

2) the `Desktop` and `Documents` folders are not shown in `Macintosh HD ==> Users ==> SoftTimur` in Finder, even though in a terminal we can see that they are physically in the folder of `SoftTimur`.

Does anyone know why it is like that?

PS: `ls -lO` returns

```
total 0
drwx------@  5 softTimur  staff  -  160 Dec 21 10:50 Applications
drwx------@  5 softTimur  staff  -  160 Dec 22 22:29 Applications (Parallels)
drwx------@ 13 softTimur  staff  -  416 Dec 22 17:41 Desktop
drwx------@  5 softTimur  staff  -  160 Dec 22 17:41 Documents
drwx------+ 20 softTimur  staff  -  640 Dec 22 21:53 Downloads
drwx------+ 63 softTimur  staff  - 2016 Dec 21 20:47 Library
drwx------+  5 softTimur  staff  -  160 Dec 22 17:41 Movies
drwx------+  6 softTimur  staff  -  192 Dec 22 17:41 Music
drwx------   4 softTimur  staff  -  128 Dec 22 22:45 Parallels
drwx------+  6 softTimur  staff  -  192 Dec 22 17:41 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  4 softTimur  staff  -  128 Dec 20 16:41 Public
drwxr-xr-x   5 softTimur  staff  -  160 Dec 22 22:34 Startup
```

PS: in Mac Finder:

[image]

Comment: Are you storing your Desktop and Documents folders in iCloud Drive? Check under System Preferences -> iCloud -> iCloud Drive -> Options, should be the first item at the top. Also run `ls -lO` and see if the Desktop and Documents folders are just hidden.

Comment: OK, I see that by default these folders are in iCloud's options. So since they are in iCloud, I cannot see these 2 folders under `Macintosh HD ==> Users ==> SoftTimur` in Finder?

Comment: Check to see if they're just hidden using `ls -lO` in the Terminal.

Comment: In the Terminal, even `ls` shows these 2 folders. What is odd is that they are not under `SoftTimur` in Finder.

Comment: Can you give me the full output of `ls -lO`? That particular command should show some of the flags.

Comment: Please see OP...

Comment: In a Finder window, can you press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>?

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to see by that shortcut? I'm using a french keyboard, shortcuts are different.

Comment: It's a show all files shortcut; I'm guessing it doesn't do anything as they're not showing as hidden (even though you're not seeing them), but I wanted to check just in case.

Comment: I did not find the shortcut, and I used `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` to show hidden files. Indeed, these 2 folders are considered as hidden files by Finder. Is it possible to change that?

Comment: Try using `chflags nohidden ~/Desktop` and `chflags nohidden ~/Documents`

Comment: `chflags` did not help...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70709/discussion-between-jmy1000-and-softtimur).

Comment: @Allan I added a screenshot...

Comment: Also need a screenshot of what you are (not) seeing in Finder.

Answer (score 2):

It is like that because your `Documents` and `Desktop` folders are stored in iCloud. Thus, they are no longer shown in your `Home` folder (the folder with your username) as they are now in the iCloud one.

This mean that files in `Documents` and `Desktop` are stored both locally on your Mac and online on iCloud as long as there is enough space available on your disk.  If your computer runs out of space or for files you have not opened in a while, they are deleted from your disk but remain available online for a download when needed.

You can remove this feature at any time in system pref.

PS: I'not an expert with the terminal but I guess artifacts could be aliases to those folders or maybe your Mac shows `Documents` & `Desktop` above iCloud by convenience.